# Firestore Security Rules - how to prevent modification of a certain field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Let's assume we have a Firestore collection called `todos`, where each todo will look something like this:

```
{
    name: "Buy milk",
    completed: false,
    user: "eYtGDHdfgSERewfqwEFfweE" // some user's uid
}
```

Now, I want to **prevent modification** of the `user` field during updates (in other words - make this field **read-only**).

Believe me, I've done my research. My `update` rule looks like this:

```
allow update: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.user
              //&& !request.writeFields.hasAny(["user"]);
              //&& !(request.writeFields.hasAny(["user"]));
              //&& !request.resource.data.keys().hasAny(["user"]);
              //&& !('user' in request.resource.data);
              //&& ('user' in request.resource.data) == false;
              //&& !('user' in request.writeFields);
```

**None** of the above (commented out) work. They all result in an error: `Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.`.

But...

It gets even more interesting! Because if we compare some of the above rules for *positive outcome* (aka `true`) they will work!

For example, this one **works perfectly** (assuming we include `user` field in our request):

```
allow update: if request.resource.data.keys().hasAny(["user"]) == true;
```

BUT this one **doesn't work** (assuming we do NOT include the `user` field in the request):

```
allow update: if request.resource.data.keys().hasAny(["user"]) == false;
```

Can anyone explain me what is going on here? Is it possible this is actually a bug in Firestore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At "Writing conditions for Cloud Firestore Security Rules" section "Data validation" example #2

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Make sure all cities have a positive population and
    // the name is not changed
    match /cities/{city} {
      allow update: if request.resource.data.population > 0
                    && request.resource.data.name == resource.data.name;
    }
  }
}
```

So `request.resource.data.user == resource.data.user` should work for you? CMIIW

Ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation

Comment: Yeah, I use this as my workaround too. But this way you **have to** include the `user` field in every request, e.g. `set({user: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid, completed: true})`. If you don't do this, you'll get an error. I would love to be able to NOT include this field at all, e.g. `set({completed: true})`

Comment: You can use set({completed: true}, {merge: true}) or update({completed: true})

Comment: Oh man, you're right. I was so focused on those security rules, but I actually used the wrong method... Thanks!

Comment: this solution doesn't work if the `user` field is initially not set.

Comment: If you are using merge to set you may leave a field blank so that it retains its current value, would this then fail as request.resource would be nil while resource.data would be nonnil? Or do rules auto match non-set fields in a merge write at time of rule execution?

Answer (score 0):

When you update a document the security rules compare the document that results from the update with the conditions of the security rules. This means that if a field exists in the document on the server but not in the data you push in the update, the security rules will see that field from the old data in the update. For example:

In the document store on the server:

```
{
  reviewerID: sam123,
  title: "It sucks",
  description: "Because it does",
  rating: 1
}
```

and then your update is:

```
{
  description: "but actually it's not so bad",
  rating: 3
}
```

Then what the security rules see in `request.resource.data` is:

```
{
  reviewerID: sam123,
  title: "It sucks",
  description: "but actually it's not so bad",
  rating: 3
}
```

Which means that even though the update didn't push a change to `reviewerID` or `title` those fields do exist in the data you're evaluating.

To make sure that the data is unchanged you need to compare the new data with the old data:

`request.resource.data.reviewerID == resource.data.reviewerID`

the line:

`!request.resource.data.keys().hasAny(["user"]);`

Would be correct in preventing the data from existing in the document. It is **not** something that would allow it to exist but make it immutable.

See:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Make sure all cities have a positive population and
    // the name is not changed
    match /cities/{city} {
      allow update: if request.resource.data.population > 0
                    && request.resource.data.name == resource.data.name;
    }
  }
}
```

From:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation

and:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow the user to create a document only if that document does *not*
    // contain an average_score or rating_count field.
    match /restaurant/{restId} {
      allow create: if (!request.resource.data.keys().hasAny(
        ['average_score', 'rating_count']));
    }
  }
}
```

From:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-fields#forbidding_specific_fields_in_new_documents